# Why am I getting the error "Cannot read property 'MAX_LENGTH' of undefined" when I try to connect to Elasticsearch using the JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect a React app to an instance of Elasticsearch in AWS using the JavaScript client. I started the React app using "npm start-react-app app" and then I installed the client using "npm install @elastic/elasticsearch".
In the official documentation, it says I can initialize the client by using:

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' })
```

All I did was paste this code in my React app and replace the localhost url with the url of my AWS ES instance.

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({ node: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com' })
```

But I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'MAX_LENGTH' of undefined**" with the following description:

```
  37 | const clientVersion = require('../package.json').version
  38 | const userAgent = `elasticsearch-js/${clientVersion} (${os.platform()} ${os.release()}-${os.arch()}; Node.js ${process.version})`
> 39 | const MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH = buffer.constants.MAX_LENGTH
  40 | const MAX_STRING_LENGTH = buffer.constants.MAX_STRING_LENGTH
  41 | 
  42 | class Transport {
```

I tried to do the same thing using the old client and everything worked perfectly. So I don't think the problem is related to the AWS ES instance. I installed the old client using "npm install elasticsearch" and I connected to the instance using:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
   hosts: [ 'https://xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com']
});
```

The issue occurs only when I use the new client. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do `console.log(buffer)` and `console.log(buffer.constants)` produce as output?

Comment: @secan I think this part is library code not OPs code.

Comment: @trixn yes, but the error seems to indicate that one of the two (either `buffer` or `buffer.constants`) is `undefined`. Understanding which one might help to find the solution in the library documentation or support.

Comment: @secan Yeah, that's because `@elastic/elasticsearch` is intended to be used in a nodejs environment (on a server) and [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) is a lib that is only available there. See the sources: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/d5f61c7833444dee9db293482c7e4fe9d510ee1f/lib/Transport.js#L25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is intended to be used in a nodejs environment on the server. You can't use it in the browser as is.

From the [repo readme](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js#browser):

> ### Browser
>
> WARNING: There is no official support for the browser environment. It
> exposes your Elasticsearch instance to everyone, which could lead to
> security issues. We recommend that you write a lightweight proxy that
> uses this client instead, you can see a proxy example [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/master/docs/examples/proxy).

Comment: Thank you. I will do some research on this topic. It's new for me.